# Uploaded media 500 server error - Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I have migrated an Umbraco install to a new server.

However, I now get a 500 server error whenever I try and open a media file.

I can upload files successfully to the root 'media' folder but I cannot seem to then navigate to these files.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: If you could upload the error message you receive it would help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other poeple have mentioned, ideally we need to see the error message. Additionally, can you check if your server can serve up files of that type from other location? If so then it's a permissions issue (check the permissions on the old server match the new one, remember to give read, write and modify permissions to "IIS_IUSRS", "Network Service" and "IUSR" Windows accounts), but if you cannot serve any files of that type at all then you need to add the MIME extensions (added in IIS - see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/ourumb-dev-forum/bugs/36514-Media-Upload-411-dosen%27t-work) suggests touching the global.asax, while [this one](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-1344) makes me wonder whether you removed the Label datatype by any chance.

What version of Umbraco are you using? I would also look in the database, in the UmbracoLog table for any errors that might point you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

What type of media files don't work?  Is it just certain extensions?  Or everything (including images)?

If it is simply certain extensions, you may need to verify that IIS is allowing those extensions.